# Second monitor freezing ... necessitates restart

Tags: dual-boot, intel-graphics, hp, monitor, external-monitor

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a 100 GB partition alongside Windows 11 on an HP Envy with an intel core i7 with integrated iRISxe. I've plugged an old Acer monitor to the HDMI port as a second monitor. Periodically the mouse pointer will not appear on the second monitor when I want to go there, which requires a restart (reboot). I see that other users are also having issues with Ubuntu 22.04 and monitors. Does Ubuntu have a solution or upgrade that will solve this issue?

Comment: Is it just the pointer, or is it the whole screen that does not update on the second monitor? What if you hover you mouse over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor , then left click and press escape on https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/pointer-lock/ , and see if your mouse returns to normal?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It happens randomly, I will try that next time it occurs. There may be some issues with the dual boot install of Ubuntu (swap space). I am going to get around to that. In the mean time there are deadlines.